# Using google mic selected language want to show below of "Google" text?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I selected "English" language so below of Google text showing English-us text using default google mic function [Image description1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JgWj.jpg)

Suppose I select any other language like (Bengali, Urdu, Tamil, Malayalam) now I want to show selected language below of Google text, I used default google mic function, is there any other option to selected language showing in default google mic.

[Image description2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylrKP.jpg)

[Image description3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bgF2.jpg)

Comment: You have to download the languages manually as stated in this [tutorial](http://stackandroid.com/tutorial/how-to-enable-offline-speech-to-text-in-android/). This will allow your app to adjust the language of your choice. Hope this helps.